# installing custom rom in Samsung galaxy s3 SGH T999

Tags: cyanogenmod

hi I m unknown from unknown I want to install custom 6.0 on my Samsung galaxy s3 SGH t999 I tried available ones but did not work cm13 rom and Google apps are installed but getting into boot loop can u tell me how I resolve this I tried all possible ways

Comment: the reason for boot loop is Unknown

Comment: How can I fix that mr

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226294

Answer (score 1):

Try to install TWRP Recovery and go to recovery mode and click wipe data and tick all without internet and external storage then wipe data then go back and click install select the file and install it